# Moto X play giving strange error

Tags: android, crash

my app at PlayStore is giving a strange ANR, it's specific to the model and the error doesn't give me clues where is the problem

this is the report at Play Console:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'motorola/lux_retla_ds/lux_uds:6.0/MPD24.65-33.1/1:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'p2c0'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 9584, tid: 9156, name: Chrome_InProcGp >>> com.leifacil.vademecum <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x301b
r0 b919d5a0 r1 00002fdb r2 0000301b r3 000000c0
r4 ba2a6d88 r5 b428c73c r6 ba2a6db8 r7 0000001b
r8 b91b0128 r9 0000305b sl 0c000000 fp 00000000
ip 00000000 sp 9d434fc8 lr 00000013 pc aa948730 cpsr 000f0030

backtrace:
#00 pc 0014a730 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxMemPoolGeneral::ReturnMemory(EsxMemType, EsxTimestamp const*, unsigned int, gsl_memdesc*)+463)
#01 pc 00145325 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxGfxMem::Destroy(EsxContext*)+644)
#02 pc 001019e5 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxResource::SetGfxMem(EsxContext*, unsigned int, EsxGfxMem*, int)+132)
#03 pc 00101a3f /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxResource::FreeSubResource(EsxContext*, EsxSubResource*)+30)
#04 pc 00101b05 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxResource::SetSubResource(EsxContext*, unsigned int, EsxSubResource*)+36)
#05 pc 00101d03 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxResource::Destroy(EsxContext*)+290)
#06 pc 001210f5 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (EglImage::Destroy()+20)
#07 pc 0011d88b /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (EglSurfaceAccess::~EglSurfaceAccess()+10)
#08 pc 0011a161 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libESXGLESv2_adreno.so (EglApi::DestroyImage(void*, void*)+64)
#09 pc 0001440d /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglDestroyImageKHR+44)
#10 pc 0036c93f /data/app/com.google.android.webview-1/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so
```